# How to call factory on page load and populate field using AngularJS?

Tags: java, html, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

On page load I want to populate a value in the dropdown list, but I am getting undefined error. I'm not sure where I am wrong in the code below. Any help will be appreciated.

CYCLE.HTML

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 fieldHeight">
    <label for="populate" class="col-md-4 required">Populate from</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <select kendo-drop-down-list
            k-options="riskImpactOptions" data-text-field="'text'"
            data-value-field="'id'" name="populate"
            k-option-label="'Select'"
            ng-model="rcsaDTO.populateFromRskAssesCycKey"
            ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
            k-data-source="riskTypeDataSource"
            id="populate">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

cycleCtrl.js

```
RcsaFactory.getPopulateCycleVal().then(function(response){
    $scope.populateRcsaCycle = response.data;
    $scope.rcsaDTO.populateFromRskAssesCycKey = $scope.populateRcsaCycle.data;
});
```

cycFactory.js

```
getPopulateCycleVal: function(key){
    return $http.get('app/rest/cycle/populate' + key);
}
```

cycle.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/cycle/populate", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public List<DropDownUtil<Object, String>> getDataForPopulateFromDrowDown() {        
    return cachingRepository.getRskCyclePopulateFrom();
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is causing your problem or not, but the url your cycFactory.js is calling is different then the RequestMapping in your cycle.java.  ('../populate' + key) != '../populate'

Comment: yes i noticed that i fixed it...

Comment: but its still not working

Comment: `getPopulateCycleVal: function(key)..` <-- its expecting a key but the call --> `RcsaFactory.getPopulateCycleVal()..` is not sending one ?

Comment: Thanks for the help i figured it out.